# How to add a Button on top of an Android keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

Hi guys i was assigned a task in my project,there i need to add a Done button on the top of Android keyboard.In my screen i have an EditText,whenever i click on the EditText it should open a keyboard along with the "Done" Button on the top of an Android keyboard.So that i can attach a Listener to that button to perform my task.Any Suggestions.

Thanks&Regards,
E.N.Krishna.

Comment: You can make the keyboard contain a done button just by setting the IME action, and you can listen for that with a keylistener. I would advise strongly against creating your own button to do this, when the keyboard is already capable of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you need the keyboard to display the Done button, you need to define this in your EditText

```
    <EditText android:text="EditText" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/editText1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

You can then catch when the user presses the Done button by using `OnEditorActionListener`

```
class DoneOnEditorActionListener implements OnEditorActionListener {
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)v.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;    
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your answer could be found if you read [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html).

Namely the concept of IME action.

Comment: @MahdeTo kindly fix the link, since android site changed their layout, it can't be located.